# Alter playback speed (tempo) using Azure Media Services

Tags: .net, audio, azure-media-services

Is it possible to alter the playback speed of the outputted audio from the “Windows Azure Media Encoder”?

I’m using the “Windows Azure Media Encoder” media processor with a "[WMA High Quality Audio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj129582.aspx#AudioEncoding)"  configuration to covert an mp3 audio file to a WMA audio file, this generally works ok.
I’d like to speed up the track so that the outputted wma file plays at double (or x) speed, is this possible?

The feature existed in the Windows Media Encoder, it was called 'Time Compression'. The description [Windows Media Encoder](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676137.aspx#XSLTsection129121120120) (search the page for "Applying time compression to your content") makes it sound like it would be ideal, but I never used it so can't say how effective it was one way or the other.

[SOX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/) has a simple [tempo](http://sox.sourceforge.net/Docs/Features) command line parameter which will "Adjust tempo without changing pitch (WSOLA alg.)" but obviously the preference is to use the "Windows Azure Media Encoder"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scott, 
No, this is not currently supported by the Azure Media Encoder.  I assume you would want pitch correction as well?  Please add your vote for it on our uservoice page [here](http://azuremediaservices.uservoice.com/forums/88965-media-services-feature-suggestions)

Comment: ideally there would be pitch correction as well, but I could live without it to start with. I couldn't see an existing uservoice item that matched so I created one here: http://azuremediaservices.uservoice.com/forums/88965-media-services-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4323657-support-altering-playback-speed-tempo-as-part-of but let me know if one already exists and I'll move my votes to it.